# Collection addAll removeAll returns boolean

Tags: java

C is a collection of type `Set<T>`, F(x) returns an collection of Set, what i want to do is to perform operations between sets like union, intersection, difference

```
// C union ( F(X) \ F(Y))
C.addAll( F(X).removeAll( F(Y)))); //error boolean because removeAll returns a boolean
```

alternative i could

```
C_aux = new HashSet<T> ( F(X));
C_aux.removeAll( F(Y)); 
C.addAll( C_aux);
```

anyway to do this without declaring the auxiliar collection ? (skip/ignore the boolean return)

Comment: The alternative way is much clearer. I would choose this way.

Comment: Why not simply A.removeAll(B);C.addAll(A); why c_aux?

Comment: Because A.removeAll(B) remove only the elements that are in both A and B

Comment: @JosemandoSobral: C_Aux pointing/contains A, so same thing happens right? Am I missing something

Comment: @Nambari because A and B does not exist they are returned sets from a Function maybe i did not explain my self clearly

Comment: @fxe: Ok, if that is the case, I think best way is your alternative. Which is cleaner.

Comment: @user714965 to simplyfy code i am representing C union ( F(o) \ F (O)), where F is a function 'o' and 'O' are inputs

Comment: C.addAll( A.removeAll(B) ? A : null); which is very hard to read

Comment: @Nambari you're write, your example is just like the alternative. my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
C.addAll(A.removeAll(B)?A:A);
```

Normally I would consider this a joke, but in this case you could save creating a list. It is still as ugly as my "decorative" plant after I forgot to water it for about 3 months... :P

**Edit:** This of course also works, but still changes A.

```
A.removeAll(B);
C.addAll(A);
```

By the way: If `A` and `B` can not be changed in the method, I think there is no way around creating a temporary list (no matter whether you safe it in a variable or not). At least if `C` can initially contain elements.

Answer (score 6):

java.util.Collection API:

```
a.retainAll(b); // intersection
a.removeAll(b); // difference
a.addAll(b); // union
```

Google Guava com.google.common.collect.Sets API:

```
Sets.union(a, b);
Sets.intersection(a, b);
Sets.difference(a, b);
```

You can write one-liner if that is what you actually need:

```
Sets.union(C, Sets.difference(F(X), F(Y)))
```

But remember that result set is read-only, so if you need real Set use `C.removeAll` instead

Comment: I don't see how this helps OP, as he clearly already knows about those methods...